# Join two dataframes on multiple conditions pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have 2 tables, first is the testappointment table and 2nd is the actualTests table. i want to join the 2 df in such a way that the resulting table should have column "NoShows". this column depicts that the person booked a appointment for that date, but actually did not show up for the test at the test date.
Example-

```
 testAppointment Table
```

| personId | testDate |
| --- | --- |
| x | 2021-02-12 |
| y | 2021-03-18 |
| x | 2020-11-01 |
| z | 2020-09-10 |
| y | 2021-01-08 |
| z | 2020-12-24 |

```
 Test Table
```

| personId | ActualtestDate |
| --- | --- |
| x | 2021-02-12 |
| y | 2021-03-18 |
| x | 2020-11-01 |
| z | 2020-09-10 |

Since, the person y(2021-01-08) and z(2020-12-24) did not showup for their tests on 2 dates hence, there is no entry for them in the test table. hence, i want to have  no-show for them in their respective rows after the two tables are joined.

Comment: z has two same dates, so why does it count as no show?

Comment: yup my bad, only y (2021-01-08) is a no show. so how do i go forward with this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do a left join and create a new column based on whether `ActualtestDate` is null:

```
result = testappointment.join(
    test, 
    (testappointment.testDate == test.ActualtestDate) & (testappointment.personId == test.personId), 
    'left'
).select(
    testappointment.personId, 
    testappointment.testDate, 
    test.ActualtestDate.isNull().alias('noshow')
)

result.show()
+--------+----------+------+
|personId|  testDate|noshow|
+--------+----------+------+
|       x|2021-02-12| false|
|       y|2021-03-18| false|
|       x|2020-11-01| false|
|       z|2020-09-10| false|
|       y|2021-01-08|  true|
|       z|2020-12-24|  true|
+--------+----------+------+
```